# Why is PIL Image.py complaining about 'palette image with transparency' when dealing with .jpgs?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg

I'm running some ML code that runs through a bunch of training images, which I cleaned up beforehand by converting to .jpg, throwing out small images etc. I get the following warning every few iterations:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py:931: UserWarning: Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be converted to RGBA images
```

which is weird since I checked that all the jpg's have 3 channels and in any case the .jpg format doesn't support transparency. Checking that bit  of code in PIL I see dragons, which is also curious:

```
    elif self.mode in ("L", "RGB", "P") and mode in ("L", "RGB", "P"):
        t = self.info["transparency"]
        if isinstance(t, bytes):
            # Dragons. This can't be represented by a single color
            warnings.warn(
                "Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be "
                "converted to RGBA images"
            )
            delete_trns = True
```

By this point in the code the filename is long gone so I can't easily put a debug line in.  Any thoughts what might be the cause?

Comment: Run `file *` in the directory containing the images and look for the *"odd bod"* if we are still allowed to say such things.

Comment: fantastic, `file` where have you been all my life